# MULTIPLICAR DOS VALORES DE INPUTS EN LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

comunidad estoy iniciando un sistema de captura de ingresos diarios en laravel, como logro multiplicar dos valores y mostrar el resultado, optube dicha tabla, pero no me muestra la info de precio y total.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradezco de todo corazon, todo aporte y apoyo a resolver mi dudas.

Comment: Pon más informacion par aque podamos ayudar. Muestra el codigo que usas y etc, por que no podemos adivinar que codigo estas implementando.

Comment: comparto un archivo txt, para que puedan visualizar parte del código  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lt7OngJWNHwa7EYsPxK_oexrl3aN_aCNrI1iAay2vXY/edit?usp=sharing